# How to show all results from a repeat loop in the Script Editor results pane

Tags: applescript, json

I'm querying the ipstack API for data with a list of IPs using a `repeat` loop and JSON Helper.

I'm looping through a list of IPs, but I can't get the Script Editor to return all the results; I only get the one `cityName` of the last IP in `theListOfips` in the results pane, `"Tallahassee"`.

How can I get the Script Editor to show a list of all cities in the result pane, with a carriage return after each?

```
 set theListOfips to {"104.137.108.23", "107.140.9.50", "146.201.166.248"}

    tell application "JSON Helper"

        repeat with theCurrentValue in theListOfips

            delay 2

            set json to fetch JSON from
   "http://api.ipstack.com/" & theCurrentValue & "?access_key=theAPIkey&fields=city"

            set cityName to city of json

        end repeat

    end tell
```

Comment: AppleScript only returns the result of the last statement executed, so you would need to build a list of the cities, adding to it each time through the loop, then return the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate solution would be to use the `Replies` pane rather than the `Results` pane in *`Script Editor`*.  It will print a live result from each AppleScript command executed during the run of a script, whereas the `Results` pane only returns the overall result of the script's execution (which equates to the result of only the final command).

The final command in your script will be `set cityName to city of json`, and so the result of your script will be the value of `cityName` after it has been set to the value from the JSON record that pertains specifically to the last IP address in your list, i.e. `"146.201.166.248"`.

So for a more comprehensive solution, you can edit your script slightly so that the last command will be one that returns what you actually want.  You can do this by first declaring a variable as an empty `list`, into which you would add an `item` of data in each iteration of your repeat loop.  After the repeat loop is complete, your final command would simply be a reference to that `list` so as to have AppleScript evaluate its contents and return the result:

```
set APIKey to "<your secret key>"
set URLRelativePath to "http://api.ipstack.com/"
set URLQueryString to "?access_key=" & the APIKey & "&fields=city"

set IPaddresses to {"104.137.108.23", "107.140.9.50", "146.201.166.248"}

set cityNames to {}

tell application "JSON Helper" to repeat with IPaddress in the IPaddresses
        fetch JSON from the URLRelativePath & the IPaddress & the URLQueryString
        set the end of cityNames to the contents of the result's city
        --OR: set the end of cityNames to the contents of {the IPaddress, the result's city}
end repeat

return the cityNames
```

This returns a list of all the city names (or a list of lists of IP address-city name pairs if you elect to use the line I commented out as an alternative).  To make this list into a single piece of text with one city per line, use the list that contains city names only; set the `text item delimiters` to `linefeed`; then coerce the `list` to `text`.  So, instead of `return the cityNames`, you would have:

```
set my text item delimiters to linefeed
return the cityNames as text
```

Comment: Thanks! That works great. It's also cleaner that what I cam up with.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch You're most welcome. Thanks for the tick.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the log() function, it will log the results to the messages pane.

Example:

```
set i to 1

repeat 10 times

    log (i)

    set i to i + 1
end repeat
```

Make sure that you open up the messages pane:
[image: messages pane]

**Edit:**
If it's important that it's only the returned value, than you could simply keep track of all the strings and add them together and return the composite. The above example modified:

```
set i to 1
set a to ""
repeat 10 times

    set a to a & i & return

    set i to i + 1
end repeat
return a
```

---

```
Result:
"1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good general demo of the principal.